# Netbeans folder icons

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'd like to understand how Netbeans 8.2 determines the icon for folders. As per the screenshot below, I have three folders with PHP code, each a WordPress plugin. None of them contain Netbeans-specific files, but something is triggering the IDE to change the folder icon. Thanks.

[image: Folders in Netbeans Files list]

Comment: It's just basic intelligent guesses based on contents. If you have e.g. a composer.json in a folder it will mark it as PHP and if you have some HTML it might mark it as a www folder.

Answer (score 0):

The response by @apokryfos gave me a start. Yes, I'm seeing that if the folder has a package.json, the folder changes to use the 'world' icon. If the folder has a nbproject folder with a project.xml, then the `type` tag in there seems to explicitly override the implied type. This helped me to understand the right vocabulary to ask this question better.

Googling for "netbeans project types" I found the [NetBeans Project Type Module Tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html) which explained the coding of custom project types - and how to specify their folder icons. From that page:

> A project type is a NetBeans Platform term for a grouping of folders
>   and files that is treated as a single unit.

For anyone who is interested, this is what I'm seeing with the latest Netbeans 8.2 nightly build.

- The Files list updates within some amount of time after one of those indicators is changed - depending on how many folders and files are in the project and its scanning time.
- A change made outside of the environment is only recognized in the Files tree after the parent folder is opened. In other words, the icon on the folder doesn't change until the IDE has a reason to look at the files it contains.
- The Projects folder list caches the folder project type, so it's not as dynamic as the Files tree. So far the only way I see to refresh icons in the Projects list is to close and re-open the IDE.